# How to customize numeric input for a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` (that represents a tip value) in my Storyboard that starts out as `$0.00`.  If the user types an `8`, I want the textField to read `$0.08`.  If the user then types a `3`, I want the textField to read `$0.83`.  If the user then types `5`, I want the textField to read `$8.35`.  How would I go about changing the input to a `UITextField` in this manner?

Comment: Why does the question look like the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28121463/451475) asked just an hour ago?

Comment: Because I was answering that user's question and was about to post it when they were intimidated and deleted their question.

Comment: In my opinion, their question was very clear.  I'm sorry if you didn't think so, but I hate to see new users intimidated instead of gently guided.

Comment: SO is about helping with code, an attempt should be made, that is how one learns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the following four steps:

1. Make your viewController a `UITextFieldDelegate` by adding that to the `class` definition.
2. Add an `IBOutlet` to your textField by <kbd>Control</kbd>-dragging from the `UITextField` in your Storyboard to your code.  Call it `myTextField`.
3. In `viewDidLoad()`, set your viewController as the textField’s `delegate`.
4. Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.
   Take the incoming character and add it to the tip, and then use the `String(format:)` constructor to format your string.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

       @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

       // Tip value in cents
       var tip: Int = 0

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           myTextField.delegate = self
           myTextField.text = "$0.00"
       }

       func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
           if let digit = Int(string) {
               tip = tip * 10 + digit
               textField.text = String(format:"$%d.%02d", tip/100, tip%100)
           }
           return false
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: When I press backspace or delete then it doesn't work. Also if I clear textfield then it still keeps going from last point unless I reset tip to zero.